# If the derivative is zero on [a, b], then the function is constant - using Heine-Borel?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I know the proof of the statement in the title using the mean value theorem but I was wondering if it can be proved using the Heine-Borel Lemma, which reads:

"Every open cover of a closed interval has a finite subcover."

(Without compactness, simple as that).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. There is no connection between compactness and derivatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Denote $I=[a,b]$ and let $f:I\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function whose differential vanishes identically.

Let $\epsilon>0$.
For any $x\in I$ we have $f'(x)=0$, so by definition of derivatives, there is $\delta_x>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon|x-y|$ whenever $|y-x|<\delta_x$ and $y\in I$.
The open intervals $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)\cap I$ cover $I$, and by Heine—Borel, finitely many of them are enough to cover it.

Let the midpoints be $a=x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n=b$ (we can always include the endpoints if we want).
For each $k$ pick a point $z_k\in (x_k,x_k+\delta_{x_k})\cap(x_{k+1}-\delta_{x_{k+1}},x_{k+1})\cap I$.
(Such a point exists since the $\delta$-intervals cover the interval $I$, as guaranteed by Heine—Borel.)
Now we have $a=x_1<z_1<x_2<z_2<x_3<\dots<x_{n-1}<z_{n-1}<x_n=b$ and each $z_k$ is within the "allowed $\delta$ range" from the points $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$.

Take any $y\in I$. Suppose $y\in [x_m,z_m]$ for some $m$.
Then
$$
|f(a)-f(y)|
\leq
|f(x_1)-f(z_1)|+
|f(z_1)-f(x_2)|+
|f(x_2)-f(z_2)|+
|f(z_2)-f(x_3)|+
\dots+
|f(x_m)-f(y)|
\leq
\epsilon|x_1-z_1|+
\dots
\epsilon|x_m-y|
=
\epsilon(y-a)
\leq
\epsilon(b-a).
$$
The other option is that $y\in[z_m,x_{m+1}]$ for some $m$, and you get the same estimate.

Since $|f(a)-f(y)|\leq\epsilon(b-a)$ for any $y\in I$ and $\epsilon>0$, you must have $f(a)=f(y)$ for all $y\in I$.
Therefore $f$ is constant.

Comment: This is a toally new application of Heine Borel Theorem. +1

Comment: @EricWofsey: I think you have misinterpreted my comment. By "totally new" I mean "totally new for me". Sorry that i did not write this explicitly.

Comment: "For each k pick a point..." - how do we know there exists such point?

Comment: "Then $|f(a)-f(y)|\leq...$" you mean that $|f(a)-f(y)|\leq|f(x1)-f(y)|$ and then uses the triangular inequality? and why is that true $|f(a)-f(y)|\leq|f(x1)-f(y)|$?

Comment: @user3697301: Note that the finite intervals selected in the conclusion of Heine Borel Theorem overlap so that the intersection of cosecutive intervals is non-empty and hence $z_{k}$ exists. The reason is that each point of $I$ must lie in the interior of such selected intervals. If there was no overlap then the end points of the selected intervals will fail be an interior point of some other selected interval.

Comment: @user3697301: The inequality is established like $$|f(a) - f(y)| = |(f(x_{1}) - f(z_{1})) + (f(z_{1}) - f(x_{2})) + \cdots + (f(x_{m})  - f(y))|$$ and then the triangle inequality is applied.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh they are overlapping because $|y-x|<\delta_x$, you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25512/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-user3697301).

Comment: @user3697301, I updated my answer a bit. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: just last thing - how did you conclude $f(a)=f(y)$? i don't see it..

Comment: @user3697301, I got that $|f(a)-f(y)|$ has to be smaller than any strictly positive number. Therefore it has to be zero.